# Using enum to reduce page object method

Tags: java, webdriver

I had written following page object class which represents user profile page. The profile contains department, teams, email and login labels and corresponding values. Initially I wrote a page object class as  -

```
public class MyProfilePage extends PageObject{

public MyProfilePage() throws Exception {
    super(departmentLabel);
    throw new IllegalStateException("This is not My Profile page");
}

private static final LabelElement departmentLabel = new LabelElement("Department Label",
        locateByCSSSelector(".department"));
private static final LabelElement teamLabel = new LabelElement("Teams Label",
        locateByCSSSelector(".teams"));
private static final LabelElement emailLabel = new LabelElement("Emails Label",
        locateByCSSSelector(".email"));
private static final LabelElement loginLabel = new LabelElement("Login Label",
        locateByCSSSelector(".login"));

public String getDepartment() {
    return departmentLabel.getText();
}

public String getTeam() {
    return teamLabel.getText();
}

public String getEMail() {
    return emailLabel.getText();
}

public String getLogin() {
    return loginLabel.getText();
}
}
```

Then I decided to use enum and reduce the number of class variable and methods -

```
public class MyProfilePage extends PageObject{

public MyProfilePage(ProfileAttribute profileAttribute) throws Exception {
    super(getProfileAttributeElement(profileAttribute));
    throw new IllegalStateException("This is not My Profile page");
}

public enum ProfileAttribute {
    DEPARTMENT("department"), TEAM("teams"), EMAIL("email"), LOGIN("login");

    private String attribute;

    ProfileAttribute(String attribute) {
        this.attribute = attribute;
    }

    public String getAttribute() {
        return attribute;
    }
}

private static HtmlElement getProfileAttributeElement (ProfileAttribute profileAttribute) {
    return new LabelElement("Profile Attribute", locateByCSSSelector("."+
            profileAttribute.getAttribute()));
}

public String getAttributeValue(ProfileAttribute profileAttribute) {
    return getProfileAttributeElement(profileAttribute).getText();
}
}
```

A curtailed version of TopHeader class which gets to the Myrofile page -

```
public class TopHeader extends PageObject {

public MyProfilePage goToManageYourAccount() throws Exception {
    manageYourAccountLink.click();
    return new  MyProfilePage(MyProfilePage.ProfileAttribute.DEPARTMENT);
}

}
```

This is how a test uses it -

```
public class MyProfileTest extends SelTestCase {

LoginUserNavigation loginUserNavigation = new LoginUserNavigation();

@Test(groups = "shouldDisplayProfileAttributesOnMyProfilePage")
public void shouldDisplayProfileAttributesOnMyProfilePage() throws Exception {
    MyProfilePage myProfilePage = loginUserNavigation
            .loginAsDefaultUser(getEnvironment())
            .getTopHeader()
            .goToManageYourAccount();
    assertThat("department is wrong", myProfilePage.getAttributeValue
            (MyProfilePage.ProfileAttribute.DEPARTMENT), is(equalTo("Technology")));
}
```

}

Have I made it any better? Could I improve it further?

Comment: This seems broken - what is that exception doing in the constructor?

Comment: constructor may indeed throw exception - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371369/can-constructors-throw-exceptions-in-java.

Comment: I don't know what you want with an object that is not eligible for usage. Should it be `abstract` !? Second, `attribute` could be `final`.

Comment: @rdllopes ```getAttributeValue``` should have been public, modified my answer.

Comment: What's `PageObject`? Can you include it?

Comment: Writing entire code of ```PageObject ``` class may make it too long. But here is the git link - https://github.com/tarun3kumar/seleniumtestsframework/blob/6d952da94fa67cc2b3a7d2d7f4fbff1f4c3763ca/src/main/java/com/seleniumtests/webelements/PageObject.java

Comment: Why do you extend `PageObject`? How are you using this code? Do you ever create a `MyProfilePage` instance?

Comment: @SimonForsberg updated question with more info

Comment: What is the result when you execute this `shouldDisplayProfileAttributesOnMyProfilePage` test? Does it pass without errors?

Comment: Seems I have been sleeping all the way in this conversation, ``` throw new IllegalStateException("This is not My Profile page");``` does not make sense. Removed it.

Comment: Please don't add code into your question after it's received answers, that invalidates answers.

Comment: well, unfortunately few conversations are stuck on ```    throw new IllegalStateException("This is not My Profile page");``` and that was not my objective of asking the question.

Comment: @Tarun That is what happens when you don't copy your exact code that you have tested and verified that it works. I'd recommend that you create a new question with your correct code if you want to start over in the review process to make the reviews focus more on the stuff that you want to focus on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides the formatting issue, I have observed two points to improve.

Since, there is an exception on constructor, the object is not eligible for usage anyway. I don't know the intention behind it but maybe you prefer a **private constructor**.

Second, `attribute` in `ProfileAttribute` could be final.

Comment: why do you say that object is not usable? I can get object of ```MyProfile``` page use it further in test to validate attributes - 

```public MyProfilePage goToManageYourAccount() throws Exception {
        manageYourAccountLink.click();
        return new MyProfilePage(MyProfilePage.ProfileAttribute.DEPARTMENT);
    }```

Comment: @Tarun try assigning it to a variable and returning the result of the variable - you cannot create a test case that will actually reach the return if you do that. Always throwing exception in constructor is... well, it's just bad.

Comment: There should not have been exception on constructor. It was a mistake on writing question ```    throw new IllegalStateException("This is not My Profile page");
```

Answer (score 5):

Throwing exceptions in the constructor is weird; you should either add a comment explaining OR just remove the exception. If you're going to always disallow creation of a PageObject, provide a static method which will do the things you want, rather than throwing exceptions all the time.

Exceptions are for exceptional flow - not for "business as usual". Right now your program reads like "... and then it crashes, which is completely normal." This sort of thing, without documentation, leads to maintenance nightmare. Why was this done? It's highly irregular! But if it was done this way, there must have been a reason? I mean, normally, there is no sane reason to do the sort of thing you just did...

```
public String getAttributeValue(ProfileAttribute profileAttribute) {
    return getProfileAttributeElement(profileAttribute).getText();
}
```

**This can be deleted.** The only constructor throws an exception, so barring weird reflection (in which case, you're doing it wrong), any methods which rely on instances cannot be called. The other option I can think of is if you have a subclass that uses this method. Then this method would see some use - but it's existence remains questionable.

Without the exception, however, you can make use of it as normal.

Comment: Throwing exception from page object constructor is an exceptional flow, when control is not on right page/page leads to 404 etc

a method relying on instance og page object can get it as - ```new MyProfilePage(MyProfilePage.ProfileAttribute.DEPARTMENT)```

why ```getAttributeValue``` can be deleted. How else would I get text content of attribute webelement?

Comment: @Tarun show me an example usage of `getAttributeValue`.

Comment: updated question with test and test uses ```getAttributeValue```

Comment: @Tarun Have you ran the test and tested it? I can see the code just fine, don't worry about the rollback (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/135934/4) - it throws the exception, yes? And then the assert never runs.

Comment: yup, assert does not run, since there is  "throw Exception" in constructor. Having it in question is wrong.

Comment: @Tarun what was the original idea behind it?

Comment: nothing, it is just plain wrong statement, posted on question in hurry

Comment: @Tarun If you want the rest reviewed, maybe you can make the changes people have suggested and ask a follow up question.

Comment: I am afraid it would be marked as duplicate as the only difference would be removal of ```thow``` from constructor.

Comment: @Tarun what about the other advice? Attribute could be made final? The formatting can be improved?

Comment: followed though and marked it as accepted answer :)

Comment: @Pimgd, even subclassing would not be possible. A subclass constructor should call any superclass constructor available and the only available throws an exception.

Comment: @rdllopes you can call `super(getAttributeValue...`, right? (EDIT: No, you can't. Compiler complains about not being able to access `this`).